# iphone - how to call struct in different file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct

I have defined a struct in a file,and now i want to use this struct in another file.i know it can use"::"to call the struct for C++, but for objective-c how to call the struct.

My.h file "ManageMarketPacket.h"

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>   
 typedef struct ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA_tag{
    short   id;
    char    exch;                  
}ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA;
@interface ManageMarketPacket : NSObject {        
}
```

My file "ManageMarketPacket.m"

```
#import "ManageMarketPacket.h"
@implementation ManageMarketPacket
@end
```

So my .m file has nothing,so my another file will use the struct,in my other file"NetWorkConnect.m"

```
#import "ManageMarketPacket.h"
@implementation NetWorkConnect
- (id)init{
    if (self==[super init]) {
       ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA quota;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

So my problem is `ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA quota;` it's incorrect...so I how to call the struct in NetWorkConnect.m?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: hmmm, why do you re-post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439575/iphone-how-to-call-struct-in-different-file You could have adjust edit your question, not post a new one, if you are asking the EXACT same question.

Comment: @kjyoung I tried telling him. I did, in fact. Mods are flagged, should fix this any minute now.

Comment: LOL. You guys should've closed the other copy and let this one live. The other one is hardly meaningful and doesn't even convey what the OP is up to.

Comment: @Bourne It's a recurcive mess at this point.

Comment: how to closed the thread,I am new here...thank you...

Comment: @Gaojian You don't need to close the thread. There is no **thread**, just your **question** and **answers** to that question. You accepted an answer, which is the right thing to do. Now the question remains to help others who have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare quota in your header file for NetWorkConnect rather than in the init method.  Then it will be an instance variable accessible from any instance methods just like any other instance variable.

e.g. if you put:

```
#import "ManageMarketPacket.h"
// ...

@interface ManageMarketPacket : NSObject {        
    ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA quota;
    // ...
}
```

in NetWorkConnect.h

then you will be able to reference it in other methods in NetWorkConnect.m (including init).

```
- (id)init{
    if (self==[super init]) {
       quota.id = 1;
       quota.exch = 'A'
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) updateMyQuote:(int)quotaId exch:(char) quotaExch {
      quota.id = quotaId;
      quota.exch = quotaExch;
}

-(void) doSomethingElseWithQuota {
      if (quota.id != someOtherId) {
           quota.exch = 'F';
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your struct instance is local to the init method block and that is why you are not able to access it elsewhere. Declare it in the block you wish to access it and play around with it. If you want to access it throughout the class, declare it in the interface for the second .m file.